# In Illustrator, how do I create a cut between two anchor points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Suppose I have a shape that looks like the top, and I want the bottom:
[image]

I want to create cuts between the highlighted anchor points. The knife tool would do what I want if I could get it to snap to anchor points, but I can't find a way to do that. Is there a way?

I tried the scissors too, but it always gives me an error saying "Please use the scissors tool on a segment or an anchor point (but not an endpoint) of a path." and I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Far as I'm aware, there's no "cut between anchors" command anywhere.

- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (White arrow) to drag and select the angled paths
- Choose `Edit > Cut` from the menu (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>)
- Select the two open end anchors on the *top* portion
- Choose `Object > Path > Join` from the menu (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>)
- Select the two open end anchors on the *bottom* portion
- Choose `Object > Path > Join` from the menu (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>)
- Choose `Edit > Paste in Front` from the menu to paste the angles paths back in place (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>)
- Choose `Object > Path > Join` from the menu 2 times to join the angled paths and close the shape. (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>)

[image]

<sub>(Animation shows CS6, but it's the same procedure in newer versions)</sub>

Comment: You can just select the middle strut cut, paste in front and join, join

Comment: Excellent point @joojaa Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

you could also also draw a line point to point and then selecting the line and object then choose "Divide" from the pathfinder

Answer (score 0):

Just further to Scott's great advice, you can also:

1. Select the four centre anchor points of the shape using the Direct Selection Tool (A) + holding shift
2. Snip all anchors points at once by hitting the scissors tool

[image: scissors]

3. Join the anchor points of the centre (and outer) shapes using the pen tool (P)